# Pesquisar e trazer id de outra tabela

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

O campo de busca pelo problema esta funcionando, porém gostaria de buscar pelo nome do cliente já que estão relacionados.

método de busca no controller

```
public function busca(OrdemRequest $request)
{
    $problema = $request->problema;
    $ordens = Ordem::where('problema', 'LIKE', "%{$problema}%")->get();
    return view('ordem.listaordens',compact('ordens'));
}
```

Rota:

```
Route::post('/busca','OrdemController@busca');
```

View:

```
<form action="/ordem/busca"method="post">   
    <div class="form-group">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="problema" placeholder="Buscar...">
```

Model ordem:

```
class Ordem extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['id','cliente_id','valor','data','problema','servico_id'];
    protected $table = 'ordens'; 
    public function produto()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(produto::class, 'produto_id');
    }
    public function servico()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(servico::class,'ordem_id','servico_id');
    }
    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class,'cliente_id');
    }   
}
```

Model cliente:

```
class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','nome','cpf','endereco','telefone','email'];
    protected $table = 'clientes';
    public function ordem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ordem::class,'cliente_id');
```

Comment: Roni, faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), vote nas respostas que lhe ajudam e também a comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

Quando precisa fazer um tipo de busca que tem uma relação, utiliza o método [join do Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) da seguinte forma:

```
public function busca(OrdemRequest $request)
{
    $problema = $request->problema;
    $ordens = Ordem::join('clientes', 'clientes.id','=','ordems.cliente_id')
        ->where('clientes.nome', 'LIKE', "%{$problema}%")
        ->get();
    return view('ordem.listaordens',compact('ordens'));
}
```

fazendo com isso a relação das tabelas e tendo a possibilidade de utilizar filtros em campos referentes as relações.

Um outra forma também seria com [whereExists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres) da seguinte forma:

```
public function busca(OrdemRequest $request)
{
    $problema = $request->problema;
    $ordens = Ordem::whereExists(function($query) use($problema)
       {
           $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
                 ->from('clientes')
                 ->whereRaw('clientes.id = ordems.cliente_id')
                 ->where('clientes.nome','LIKE',"%{$problema}%")
       })  
        ->get();
    return view('ordem.listaordens',compact('ordens'));
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***:</sub>

- [Database: Query Builder - Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins)
- [Database: Query Builder - whereExists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas Virgilio.

Comment: Caro @RoniCardoso você pode votar a favor da resposta, na seta superior e aceitar a resposta como sendo a solução da sua pergunta que é logo abaixo a seta apontado para baixo. Ajude a comunidade a crescer, já tem duas questões assim ...